# Negative lookahead matches from the previous match

Tags: ruby, regex, regex-lookarounds

```
signals.Signals$MsgSig:
cmdResponse {
ap {
.....
req {
   Id: 192
.......
}
res {
Status: Received
.........
Id: 192
.........
}
...
}
....
}
sysContainer
signals.Signals$MsgSig:
cmdResponse {
ap {
.....
req {
Id: 192
.......
}
res {
Status: VALID
.........
Id: 192
.........
}
...
}
....
}
sysContainer
signals.Signals$MsgSig:
cmdResponse {
ap {
.....
req {
   Id: 193
.......
}
res {
Status: Received
.........
Id: 193
.........
}
...
}
....
}
sysContainer
signals.Signals$MsgSig:
cmdResponse {
ap {
.....
req {
Id: 193
.......
}
res {
Status: VALID
.........
Id: 193
.........
}
...
}
....
}
sysContainer
```

I'm trying to implement negative lookahead for the search. 
Signal starts from Signals$MsgSig: and ends at sysContainer. I need to filter based on the IdValue and Status.

```
Status = "VALID"
IdValue = "193"
aFile     = File.read('C:\Users\Documents\Application.log')

 aFile.match(/(?x)Signals\$MsgSig:\n((?!Signals\$MsgSig:).)*?
                             Id:\W+#{IdValue}\n((?!Signals\$MsgSig:).)*?sysContainer\s\{/m).to_s
```

Here I want to fetch a particular MsgSig: tat has Id value 192 and status as valid. In the above regex where should I add the search for "status".

If I add a search like the one below, it matches from the first MsgSig with IdValue 192.

```
     aFile.match(/(?x)Signals\$MsgSig:\n((?!Signals\$MsgSig:).)*?
 Id:\W+#{IdValue}(.*?)autoProgramStatus:\W+#{apStatus}((?! Signals\$MsgSig:).)*?sysContainer\s\{/m).to_s
```

Please let me know what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried your code, and I think you've mistaken the regexp by adding the redundant `\{`.

```
aFile.match(/(?x)Signals\$MsgSig:\n((?!Signals\$MsgSig:).)*?Id:\W+#{IdValue}\n((?!Signals\$MsgSig:).)*?sysContainer\s/m).to_s

# => "Signals$MsgSig:\ncmdResponse {\nap {\nreq {\n   Id: 192\n}\nres {\nStatus: Received\nId: 192\n}\n}\n}\nsysContainer\n"
```

p.s.1

I don't think there is a need to use negative lookahead, and removing the negative lookahead part the code can also work.

```
aFile.match(/(?x)Signals\$MsgSig:\n(.)*?Id:\W+#{IdValue}\n(.)*?sysContainer\s/m).to_s

# => "Signals$MsgSig:\ncmdResponse {\nap {\nreq {\n   Id: 192\n}\nres {\nStatus: Received\nId: 192\n}\n}\n}\nsysContainer\n"
```

p.s.2

To solve this problem myself, I would do it by

```
str = '' # the first block of code of your post
parts = str.scan(/signals\.Signals\$MsgSig:\n(.*?)\nsysContainer/m).flatten
# => [
  "cmdResponse {\nap {\nreq {\n   Id: 192\n}\nres {\nStatus: Received\nId: 192\n}\n}\n}",
  "cmdResponse {\nap {\nreq {\nId: 192\n}\nres {\nStatus: VALID\nId: 192\n}\n}\n}",
  "cmdResponse {\nap {\nreq {\n   Id: 193\n}\nres {\nStatus: Received\nId: 193\n}\n}\n}",
  "cmdResponse {\nap {\nreq {\nId: 193\n}\nres {\nStatus: VALID\nId: 193\n}\n}\n}"
]
parts.detect{|s| s.match /(.*)Id: 192(.*)Status: VALID(.*)/m }
# => "cmdResponse {\nap {\nreq {\nId: 192\n}\nres {\nStatus: VALID\nId: 192\n}\n}\n}"
```